# SQL database returns NULL and instead of my TEXT value

Tags: sql, postgresql, reactjs, axios

I'm having problems pushing a value to my database in the 'question_sub' field. I'm able to console log the string value fine. All other fields are working as expected.
Heres' the table:

```
CREATE TABLE questions
(qquestion_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
qdate_added timestamp default now(),
question TEXT,
quser_id int REFERENCES users(user_id),
qtopic_id int REFERENCES subjects(subject_id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
question_sub TEXT 
 );
```

Axios post:

```
    axios.post(url, {
    question: newQuestion,
    qtopic_id: id,
    question_sub: sub
    })
```

This is what's being returned to my database on a new post:

```
{
 qquestion_id: 10,
 qdate_added: "2017-05-28T21:28:55.593Z",
 question: "Hows react work with node?",
 quser_id: null,
 qtopic_id: 3,
 question_sub: null
```

}

I also tried NOT NULL in the field but then I cannot Post to the database. Appreciate any help!

Comment: what's the actual text to go in the sub?

Comment: @maSTAShuFu I'm grabbing the text from state 
  let sub =   this.state.search

Which it is logging correctly as a string

Comment: can you please post the source of the data

Comment: let sub = this.state.search

Comment: and i you print sub does it give a value?

Comment: Yes, returns a string value which I've been able to use and access in other functions

Comment: okay... im totally blind here so goodluck